# Google MySQL fails with ERROR 2013 HY000 system error 2

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-sql

I have a D8 google mysql instance. I'm running an etl process trying to push about 100GB of data in but the script keep stopping because of the error.
In order to get it working I have to restart the mysql instance and then re run the process from where it failed. Any help is greatly appreciated. I haven't found anything on google.

Answer (score 0):

This error tends to mean the connection to the MySQL server was lost at some point. As mentioned in this ['Lost connection to MySQL server'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html) article, this error may be encountered when writing a significant number or rows.

The article suggests setting the [`net_read_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout) to something greater than the default value of 30 seconds. You may also want to consider breaking up your write tasks as well.